# How To Achieve Variable Number of Indexes For nth

Tags: clojure

My question is how can I extract a number of elements from a sequence without knowing how many at compile time. Using partial came to mind, but I've been having difficulty pulling out elements instead of sequences.

I would like to achieve the sequence generated by the interleave below, but without coding in a finite number of map forms.

```
(def s1 [[:000-00-0000 "TYPE 1" "JACKSON" "FRED"]
         [:000-00-0001 "TYPE 2" "SIMPSON" "HOMER"]
         [:000-00-0002 "TYPE 4" "SMITH" "SUSAN"]])

(interleave (map #(nth % 0 nil) s1) 
            (map #(nth % 2 nil) s1) 
            (map #(nth % 3 nil) s1))

(:000-00-0000 "JACKSON" "FRED" 
 :000-00-0001 "SIMPSON" "HOMER" 
 :000-00-0002 "SMITH" "SUSAN")
```

If I do the following

```
(def cols [0 2 3])

(defn f1
    [s1 col]
    (nth s1 col nil))

(map (partial f1 s1) cols)
```

I get

```
([:000-00-0000 "TYPE 1" "JACKSON" "FRED"]\
 [:000-00-0002 "TYPE 4" "SMITH" "SUSAN"] nil)
```

I believe I know why this is happening. The cols param is acting like a sequence selector rather than an element selector within a sequence. I would like to pull several elements out of each sequence. How can I pull elements out of each sequence?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `get-in` function to access nested data structures, like so:

```lisp
(def cols [0 2 3])

(defn f1 
  [s1 col] 
  (map #(get-in s1 [% col] nil) (range (count s1))))

(apply interleave (map (partial f1 s1) cols))

(:000-00-0000 "JACKSON" "FRED" 
 :000-00-0001 "SIMPSON" "HOMER" 
 :000-00-0002 "SMITH" "SUSAN")
```

Comment: Multo Bene! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this a bit more succinctly using `for` and `partition`:

```
user> (defn get-cols [s cols] (partition (count cols) (for [ws s c cols] (ws c))))
#'user/get-cols
user> (get-cols [[:000-00-0000 "TYPE 1" "JACKSON" "FRED"]
            [:000-00-0001 "TYPE 2" "SIMPSON" "HOMER"]
            [:000-00-0002 "TYPE 4" "SMITH" "SUSAN"]]
            [0 2 3])
((:000-00-0000 "JACKSON" "FRED") (:000-00-0001 "SIMPSON" "HOMER") (:000-00-0002 "SMITH" "SUSAN"))
```

This will also preserve the original groupings.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm adding it to my bag of skills.

Comment: My variable names kind of stink.  This will only work with vectors due to the indexing I'm doing in the for '(ws c)'.  To work with all sequences you'd need to use nth instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
(apply concat (map (juxt first #(nth % 2) #(nth % 3)) s1))
```

This first collects the columns from s1 into intermediate vectors and then flattens those vectors one level, leading to the result.

Two very handy functions here:

- "apply concat" is like "flatten", but only one level deep
- juxt returns a function A that applies the arguments passed to juxt (which must be functions) to the value that is passed to A and returns a vector of the results.